# Create class name in one button and send to second button

Tags: c#

I try to make a neural network.
I try create one nn with one button and read it on the second but I
don't know how send local variables to second button.

```
private void pokaz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int[] cos = { Int32.Parse(a1.Text), Int32.Parse(a2.Text), Int32.Parse(a3.Text) };
   siecneuronowa net = new siecneuronowa(cos);

}


private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < net.wagi.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < net.wagi[i].Length; j++)

        {
            for (int k = 0; k < net.wagi[i][j].Length; k++)
            {
                diagnoza.AppendText(net.wagi[i][j][k].ToString("R"));
                diagnoza.AppendText(" ");

            }
            diagnoza.AppendText("\r\n");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: make it a member of the class.

Comment: A private member of class should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare class lever variable(as member of class):

```
private siecneuronowa net;
```

Then in `pokaz_Click` replace this line:

```
siecneuronowa net = new siecneuronowa(cos);
```

by this:

```
net = new siecneuronowa(cos);
```

In `Button_Click` you will get access to same variable that was initialized in `pokaz_Click`.